# Having trouble adding a document to a collection of a specific user in Firestore

Tags: firebase, kotlin, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to allow a logged in user to select a film from a recyclerview that will take them to a new activity where they will have the option to select a button that will allow them to save the film to their list of watched films.

I want the button select to add a film object, that holds information of the film, as a document of a sub-collection of movies, with that sub-collection of movies being within a document of the user ID, which is in a collection of users. The code I have below crashes when I press the "add movie" button.

```
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()


    val film: Film? = intent.getParcelableExtra("EXTRA_FILM")

    val title = film?.title
    val year = film?.year.toString()
    val genre = film?.genre.toString()
    val rating = film?.rating.toString()
    val runtime = film?.runtime.toString()
    val votes = film?.votes.toString()

    val movieInfo = "$title ($year) \n\n $genre \n\n Runtime: $runtime \n\n Rating: $rating ($votes Votes) "

    binding.tvTitle.text = movieInfo

    binding.btnAddMovie.setOnClickListener {
        if (film != null) {
            addToWatched(film)
        }
    }

}

//db has been initialized as type FirebaseFirestore
fun addToWatched(film: Film){
    auth.currentUser?.let { db.collection("users").document(it.uid)
        .collection("movies").add(film) }
```

Comment: Hi there, are you checking **logs** in the IDE to see what's the error? 
Moreover are you trying to check **if user logged in** or you have already checked it and you just **need to add film** to the **movies** collection?

Comment: @profiile_samir i was not checking logs(im new to android studio and coding), but using the logcat i was able to find the fatal error that was making my app crash, so thank you for that!

Comment: it's nothing, happy to help! 
One more quick tip is you can try to use **breakpoints** for debugging as well.
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Once i checked the logcat, i was able to see that i confused initializing a variable with delcaring a variable, and forgot to actually initialize the db variable to a value. so the following works:

```
fun addToWatched(film: Film){
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    auth.currentUser?.let { db.collection("users").document(it.uid)
        .collection("movies").add(film) }
}
```